# Fix intellisense to provide correct completion list on sub property used within function overloads

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am trying to create an overload to a generic function where the return type of a function is determined by the value of a property on the object provided as "props" to the function.  The function has a required generic type which is used also in the return type though it has no affect on which return type is returned.

I cannot add another generic type because I'll either have to define it manually or if I set a default type and use it on the first parameter to be inferred by the given parameter, it won't actually infer from it and will simply use the default type - very annoying.

I've got close to solving it, but the only issue I have left is that the intellisense for the property value is not showing all the available values for that property and I was hoping someone with a tiny bit more knowledge of TypeScript could help me past this final hurdle.

I have a [link to the typescript playground code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=39&pln=28&pc=50#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogNwKZigFQJ4AckwLwwDKGAtgEYgA2AFAORLKqY60CUA3ALABQPU2uAKqQArmQjAATgEsyuAtVb4AfDAQhpAEy7d%20OGAEEwGAGIiwwKNPAAeAEpIoIyWGbyYAQ2OqFAOn8ekgDmEABcnsYA2gC6SniqDk4ubjo80qhIkgBmHsC4hOlBlEgOECKUUIgoUADCkkgeUEgACpIgWBAwAN48MDAkIJpI4bRYHhDQABZtIkGTtDoAvjxpGdm5uAaSkh4YpeWVjLX1jS1tHd29-YNIAPwjoBbO9ai0MAA%20MLTpALRJYAseMteLoBPAjnUGk1Wu1OgQCmAiiUkGUKlVUJDTjCLp8tjs9iiDujjlCzrCVqD9Hjdvs0UcACJIYpBU42MwWNwwJAADyaYE0nSMpnMlmsYHwhmM7NF4B8MGo1CGzNO4WlbjiqmEZXEUlkSCUADJujBIsS3NERoF8QsYIsdHp8oVirTDtVGcqmmyRZyeXyBZLhRYrOAJULpcGwHKFUqkCymqrvQINTAtWIJDI5IbjaajuaRhAnUgbXa%20GDie7Y6y1WDfSh-WGRRHQ1LG2K5dSCajXagK3GkF6OQJVJ8EUiXeWmZXPdWcMpUtwsq2Q1JSQPgD7eXXBS2g23FOEO%20OGZO%202u3HOeIvd8uTtPE-pa-zt4GZZHqFhzmFDNsaYS6dVMWhT9WAPH9OyJY8PX7GckAvBcl3FFcq3vXBH3rHdX2Ud9P3CUdnT-bsSSxYDcMLI83RPZDB1nHQr1fGAkLvajUM3J8A3DPcP1hcJiUAskLgILpFhA8EKKgs8h0ubg%20nqf4YDAcpKE8TpzAAazAEAAHdxXGUSe0opj1yHJYKQAelMmAoEmXA5EoLSYE0kBJFUzocGyJBLEoDB-F8Hk8iwWArMaSzrJgdImkoShpAgFAYpgLInOuIYYBALIskyTpwC8hjwGAZ5qhSyQwrAP5nDAAAaMLYE0EAUXkkBYFS9KirGCYrJmOZlIiGAsBACZZGKNQPEoERcFSpKkF8HhHmgTwJUY-tFHiaAZERLCugmkZWqmDr5ltDgYHMyyBHGjx8DweEyIIicoJgGwfh%20HLtg8qBpvAWayHm29FtYZaoFWoJ1s2r5Hjy57Xn29hDosh1xs%20i6CEPa7IKnXB7se0BnssN7IFgYAvtXJblBWwogYGIYRl%20f43mEqGjthrIGPOxGwPI-TbvRp76mxkFTIAKj4EAYHqLAouAU5%20gwMKJlGyr6gGZAQtwbb2pAWZJks314raEglYmnrzkyfhPAoZBKogIXpFgOyQBcmAotU3ArOi0IKRm2AzoIBabCJkm1uoDbyeGL4aY4CkrJQfoPEdmAynqGAMDVoqwYtoropgOQoE0pBI4jyzHJgABHEQGrqjxTdwLxNANlFOksSQlIAaljsY8giavE5EWhItjnOqpSsBsqajKcqecGPf5YrSpcLr2gjCAppBABJToI-jrwpc03ZLKF4eiuGpT2r7oPOgQaQzvCpkopiyBK8n6BpB7oJHD1mQ5lgWSyuOnAIFuHg%20dMkAA) so that you can tinker about with it in it's simplest form.

Below is the code too:

```
const EventType = Symbol('eventType');

type Unsubscribe = () => void;
type AnyFunction<ReturnType = any> = (...args: any[]) => ReturnType;

interface SingleResultEventCreateProps {
  mode: 'passthrough';
}

interface ArrayResultEventCreateProps {
  mode?: 'concurrent' | 'in-turn';
}

type EventCreateProps = SingleResultEventCreateProps | ArrayResultEventCreateProps

type ArrayResultEventDelegate<FuncType extends AnyFunction = AnyFunction> = ((delegate: FuncType) => Unsubscribe) & { [EventType]: 'array'; };
type SingleResultEventDelegate<FuncType extends AnyFunction = AnyFunction> = ((delegate: FuncType) => Unsubscribe) & { [EventType]: 'single'; };
type EventDelegate<FuncType extends AnyFunction = AnyFunction> = ArrayResultEventDelegate<FuncType> | SingleResultEventDelegate<FuncType>;

function create<FuncType extends AnyFunction>(): ArrayResultEventDelegate<FuncType>;
function create<FuncType extends AnyFunction>(props: ArrayResultEventCreateProps): ArrayResultEventDelegate<FuncType>;
function create<FuncType extends AnyFunction>(props: SingleResultEventCreateProps): SingleResultEventDelegate<FuncType>;
function create<FuncType extends AnyFunction>(props: EventCreateProps = {}): EventDelegate<FuncType> {
  return null as unknown as EventDelegate<FuncType>;
}

// the below works perfectly...except that the intellisense for mode offers only concurrent or in-turn, it does not offer passthrough as an possible value of mode.
const a = create<()=>string>({ mode: 'passthrough' }); // typeof a === SingleResultEventDelegate <-- correct
const b = create<()=>string>({ mode: 'concurrent' }); // typeof b === ArrayResultEventDelegate <-- correct
const c = create<()=>string>({ mode: 'in-turn' }); // typeof c === ArrayResultEventDelegate <-- correct

/*
to replicate my issue, remove the passthrough text from the mode property above, so it looks like this:

const a = create<()=>string>({ mode: '' });

then make sure your cursor is between the two quotes above and press ctrl + space and you'll see it only offers concurrent and in-turn as options.

Is there any way to offer all three modes via intellisense and still get the right return types?
*/
```

Comment: Please also put the example code as plaintext in your question post itself; playground links are a great supplement but shouldn't be the only place the code is presented.

Comment: The IntelliSense thing seems like a known issue, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44183.  Is that your main question?  If so, could you [edit] so that the title and summary are primarily about completion lists and and not the return type?  And then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8onEW) meet your needs?

Comment: If that approach works for you and you edit your question to include the example code and to make the question primarily about IntelliSense with overload, then I will write up an answer explaining it. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that worked perfectly! Thank you, I have edited the question as you have suggested.  I struggled with the title - if you can think of a better, more concise one, I'd be happy to amend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've run into a missing feature of TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#44183](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44183).  TypeScript seems to choose just one of the overloads from which to show potential completions.  You could give that issue a  but it's not clear when or even if this will ever be addressed.

---

One possible approach to deal with this is for you to provide a dummy overload which has *all* the completions you want to support, but will never actually be selected when you call the function.  Sort of a "documentation-only" overload.  It could look like this:

```
// call signature 1
function create<F extends AnyFunction>(
): ArrayResultEventDelegate<F>;

// dummy overload for intellisense only
function create<F extends AnyFunction>(
  props: (ArrayResultEventCreateProps | SingleResultEventCreateProps) & { ugh: never }
): ArrayResultEventDelegate<F> | SingleResultEventDelegate<F>;

// call signature 2
function create<F extends AnyFunction>(
  props: ArrayResultEventCreateProps
): ArrayResultEventDelegate<F>;

// call signature 3
function create<F extends AnyFunction>(
  props: SingleResultEventCreateProps
): SingleResultEventDelegate<F>;
```

So I've added a call signature before the two you are having trouble with.  It accepts a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of both the input props types, so it will suggest both.  But it also is [intersected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) with `{ugh: never}`, so the input needs to have an `ugh` property of type `never`.  This is extremely unlikely to happen, so when you actually call `create()` it should never select this combined overload.

Let's make sure it works.  This stuff still behaves how you want:

```
const a = create<() => string>({ mode: 'passthrough' }); 
 // typeof a === SingleResultEventDelegate <-- correct
const b = create<() => string>({ mode: 'concurrent' }); 
// typeof b === ArrayResultEventDelegate <-- correct
const c = create<() => string>({ mode: 'in-turn' }); 
// typeof c === ArrayResultEventDelegate <-- correct
```

So the dummy overload is not chosen.  But that overload now shows you the intended list of possible string completions:

```
const d = create<() => string>({mode: ""})
//                                     ^  "concurrent"
//                                        "in-turn"
//                                        "passthrough"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAogNwKZigFQJ4AckwLwwDKGAtgEYgA2AFAORLKqY60CUA3ALABQPU2uAKqQArmQjAATgEsyuAtVb4AfDAQhpAEy7d+OGAEEwGAGIiwwKNPAAeAEr4YAQ2OqFAOk9PJAcwgAuZ2MAbQBdJTxVOx0eaVQkSQAzJ2BcQjifSiQ7JAgRSihEFCgAYUkkJygkAAVJECwIGABvHhgYEhBNJEDaLCcIaAALOpEfQdodAF8eWPiklNwDSUknDBy8gqLUMoqq2vrGlu42jq6Afh7QCxFl4toYAB8YWjiAWigbsAmead5dAXgjFK5UqNTqDUc6TAmWyuXyhSBO1B+whTyWKzWcM2iJBe3BEBm-306NW63hWygABEkFkfKCbCYYEgAB5VMCaRpGUzmSzWMCOLlmCxWcBuGDUahdWmgwImCKqYR5cRSWRIJQAMmaMGCFOYSFCPW8GImMEmOj0aQyWTJ2OK1OlVQZTNZKA5hmMQt54AFHp5IrAYolUqQdKqsvlMEVYgkMjkGq1OqBeoNzwgVqQJrNfABFPtIfpjJZbLdgr9fJ93OFfLFJMxGwRdpp+cdJlUTyhMJtDdQedDSAZyhi3AA9MOYMAnJRKDA0z4wJUbrgAIw8RJl71SXb9wsu9mc31V0XUHisQK1ru5pt9gdD0cwTQiEgkDAwEDISSUEBOTQwRIgSQwHEVRTtIEAoGBr5gJQGCruu-KbgWzrFvulZegGx7HDAWD4oE1Dnli3bAluKKNO26YXjixH4vGTQwKMgyBGADAJKaJ5nsspIEZeDrbm2RDkVxQK9gWg6EneE5TjO0hzgu5QwAATLBh7wbi25Ia6KGev6ygYW02EHOxGIUcUSJ4gcbGGBxdbkkJV4ibeY4SdOs7zh8ckAMxKWh46qU6RYae6qHabpWE4fx0LWoJJmqSRFkdpF9bcc2vEOYBJBYFkJDFJUfJef6Plbn5u4lgeaE6a0oUGYC0VUQcjhNL8p7VT2dktqoRxtOUbn8mA+TTv0dFgAA1mAIAAO78gNSXXq2UyElc0DOI4CGOooKgzlAMjQjptGnN0zx9AMUDDCA9H3JMHAwHeFogIkS14A94WdlFLU8TANivK847-uUlg8AtsBkMtvlrZEG1bT4O3tJ0+20FcwA3OUqDnZd10CLdMBAw9BD4YltlvR9X2gLcf3cAD47A4VoOqNAENQ3tPRvN1KPsFdY43XdwD4I9uM2Y2BOfd9JNQGJjngItP4ECt-bU+DGQ7QzMAAERKxdPB3m0mta9rOu63rmsAHowIAvBuAOS7yvw4jxRK+rY76-bDv22bytM58Nsjnbjte97ztK4dQwjGMStAA)